# Chrome overlapping web pages

Tags: 18.04, google-chrome

A couple of months ago with an Ubuntu or Chrome update it started happening: I can see parts of another page when I switch tabs, or click links text begins to overlap.

Scrolling is also messed up, everything gets mixed. There were several Chrome updates since and I reinstalled it, didn't help.

See the picture below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Upgraded to Ubuntu 20.04 and Chrome worked fine. Then it happened again after closing the laptop and opening it again(stand by mode). I rolled back to nvidia 435 and it is still happening. Probably just the laptop being old(~4years).